# How to set individual mail for each admin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress site with more than 10 admins. I want to set individual web mail for each admin so that when they login to the site's admin panel, they can see the mails sent to them.

In front-end  there will be a contact form with a combo box in it. From that combo box visitors can select which admin they want to send mail to.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: This is the wrong site for this question.  StackOverflow is for questions about writing programs, not system administration.  Try the Server Fault site that you can access from the "StackExchange" dropdown above.

Answer (score 0):

Right question. please go for the custom email plugin [WP Change Default Email]. thanks